# Practice AP Physics B Exam Question regarding Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, spring

I am trying to review momentum for the AP exam coming up. I will be taking the AP Physics C exam for Mechanics, but I was just practicing on any free response questions I could find and I came across this one. It is from 1983, free response number 2. It says:

> *A block of mass $M$ is resting on a horizontal, frictionless surface, and it is attached as shown above to a relaxed spring of spring constant $k$. A second block of mass $2M$ and initial speed $v_0$ collides with and sticks to the first block. Develop expressions for the following quantities in terms of $M$, $k$, and $v_o$.*
>
> *a.) $v$, the speed of the blocks immediately after impact.*
>
> *b.) x, the maximum distance that the spring is compressed.*

[image: The diagram that came with the problem]

So I got (a) pretty easily, just by using conservation of momentum. I found the result of $$v=\frac23 v_0$$

For part b, I began by finding the change in Kinetic Energy of the 2 blocks from immediately after impact to the point where their velocity is zero as a result of the negative work that the Spring does on the blocks. I found that $$K_i=\frac12(3M)\left[\frac23v_0\right]^2 = \frac23Mv_0^2$$
and that
$$K_f=0$$

I then equated this change in $K$ with the Work done by the spring and got
$$-\frac23Mv_0^2 = \frac12kx_i^2 - \frac12kx_f^2 = \frac12kx_0^2 - \frac12k(x_0-x)^2$$
I then tried to solve this equation for x, which is the distance that the spring is compressed, and found that
$$x=\frac12*(x_0+sqrt({x_0^2+\frac43\left(\frac{Mv_0^2}k\right)})$$
from the quadratic formula. Now, in theory, I don't really see anything wrong with this, but according to solutions I found online, people have been equating the change in K with the change in momentum, and having this equation: $$\frac23Mv_0^2 = \frac12kx^2$$
Can anyone explain why this equation would be true, or failing that, where I may have gone wrong in my own calculation? I appreciate the help.

Comment: It's the same as your equation, it's just that we're defining $x_0=0$ and $x_0-x\to x$ in the last equation.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I guess I got a little confused because the spring was anchored at the right, and not at the left, like I'm used to.

Answer (score 1):

That equation is actually equating the kinetic energy of the system of blocks with the potential energy of the spring

$K=\frac{1}{2}(3M)(\frac{2v_0}{3})^2$

$P=\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$

Then simplifying Kinetic Energy and equating the two gives as you found online

$\frac{2}{3}M(v_0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$